# Expected identifier or '(' missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Am getting this problem which I have commented in my main file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // Create an instance of Person
    Person *person = [[Person alloc]init];

    // Give the instance variables interesting values
    [person setWeightInKilos:96];
    [person setHeightInMeters:1.8];

    // Call the body mass index
    float bmi = [person bodyMassIndex];
    NSLog(@"person has a bmi of %f", bmi);

    }
    return 0;                           // Expected identifier or '('
 }                                       // Expected external declaration
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {
    float heightInMeters;
    int weightInKilos;
}

// You will be able to set those instance variables using these methods
- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h;
- (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w;

// This method calculates the body weight index
- (float)bodyMassIndex;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h{
    heightInMeters = h;  
}

- (void)setWeightInKilos:(int)w {
    weightInKilos = w;
}

- (float)bodyMassIndex {
    return weightInKilos / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);  
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a stray `}` in your program before the `return 0;`. The error is rather misleading. You may want to switch over to using LLVM instead of GCC (this will get you faster compilation too, not just better errors).

Comment: Thank you; that did the trick. I am using the Apple LLVM 3.0 compiler, so I'm not sure why it returned the error.

Comment: @pdenlinger: You are? Huh, with that error I expected it to be GCC. Seems like LLVM could certainly do a better job here. Would you mind filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com)?

Comment: I'm not a registered Apple developer, how do I file? Can I send a link to this page to an Apple bug filing email address?

Comment: @pdenlinger: All you need is an Apple Developer Connection account, which is free (only the iOS and Mac developer programs cost money, you can register for free [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/)). With an ADC account, you can file bugs at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com). The bug report page should explain how to file the report. If you can take your code and wrap it in a sample Xcode project which, upon Build, will demonstrate the issue, then you can attach the entire project to your report.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra close brace at the bottom of your main function.  Right above the "return 0;" line.

Answer (score 0):

What is the closing bracket do before your return in your main function? I think you closed 1 to many.